# Same Google Cloud Storage upload script works from one PC, but not the other, Why?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication, gcloud-node

I'm trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage from Node.JS (using gcloud package) with Service Account credentials and I get "invalid_grant" error (probably authorization error).

When I try to do this from another computer - it work fine, the error only occurs on my PC.

```
var gcloud = require('gcloud')({
    projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx31032015',
    keyFilename: './keyfile.json'
});

var storage = gcloud.storage();

var bucket = storage.bucket('test.testBucket.com');

bucket.upload('test.png', function (err, file) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Is the `keyfile.json` corresponding to a service account on your project?
- Are you using the correct project id?
- Is your system clock well-calibrated?

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, I'm glad to hear that. Yep, often cryptographic programs designed for real-time flows will fail if the system clocks aren't sufficiently sync'd.